# D8 algorithm to get flow direction in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, algorithm, hydrology

I am using `ArcGIS 10` for the get the flow direction from DEM. I wonder about the algorithm they have used while calculating flow direction. It is mentioned there that it is using D8 model. D8 model should have the value `1,4,8,16,32,64` and 128. But I am getting the value from 1 to 255. Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

I want the actual values of `D8` model `( 1, 4,8,16,32,64 and 128)` in flow direction rather than 1 to 255.

Is it possible to get that value?

Comment: As stated below, filling sinks is often done to standardize the DEM for any further analysis.  The reason you are having values other than the D8 directions is because a cell that is part of a sink will have multiple neighbors with the same lower z-value.  To define a flow direction for these cells, the D8 direction of the cells with the same z-value are summed leading to values other than the D8 (e.g. 4 + 8 = 12).  Filling sinks will reduce or eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Values other than the D8 values indicate that you have sinks in your DEM. Try the work flow shown here..

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Deriving_runoff_characteristics/009z0000005p000000/

Answer (score 0):

The raster you are using is probably an eight bit raster in which the values will range from 1 to 255 regardless of the algorithmic values.